# Can the older MiKTeX 2.1 files be used with the newer MiKTeX 2.9 and its TeXworks user interface

Tags: miktex, installing

I am a new LaTeX user, and new to this Stack Exchange, so please go easy on me!

I have a user manual having multitudes of bounding box issues because the current 2.9 version of MiKTeX (basic-miktex-2.9.7386-x64.exe) seems to be more strict than the older MiKTeX 2.1 in which the LaTeX code was written.

I found a set of instructions that are supposed to make it work, but it's still not working for me.  Here are the instructions:

> Here is the procedure for duplicating my MikTex 2.1 setup.
>
> 1) Copy the zip file at:
>         \[...Network_Location...]\LATEX\MiKTeX 2.1\texmf.zip
>        to your local PC.
>
> 2) Extract it to the boot drive (C: not C:\texm) at the root level.
>
> If you extract to c:\texmf you will create an extra level and MikTex
>   will not function properly as currently configured.
>
> 3) Add the path specification:
>
> ```
>  c:\texmf\miktex\bin
>
> to the Windows PATH environmental variable.
> ```
>
> Open up a CMD window and verify you can start the latex application:
>
> D:\PAWSUA_UG2_5>latex This is TeX, Version 3.14159 (MiKTeX 2.1)
>   **
>
> You should be able to compile now and generate PDF files with
>   correctly sized images.

When I followed the above directions, it was on top of a current MiKTeX 2.9 installation.

I have followed all of the directions, including verifying that Latex runs, and shows version 2.1.

Then I tried to use TeXworks, but the images still come in messed-up.  I even generated a .DVI directly from the LaTeX 2.1 command line interface.  There seems to be some interaction between the two versions!

I would really still like to work in TeXworks, and I just have no idea whether it can work with the older version 2.1 instead of the current 2.9.  Is it possible?  I don't want to have to reformat the entire several-hundred page manual according to the newer 2.9 version.  Help!

---

EDIT: Here is some source code and a Log file to help diagnosis and getting help.

Before I show you the bounding box problems in code, I have to show you what I am experiencing visually in the generated PDF's.  Here is a side-by-side comparison of a picture coming in badly on the left in MiKTeX 2.9 next to what it should look like on the right, rendered in MiKTeX 2.1 (by somebody else). The pictures have been slightly blurred and/or obscured (by grey rectangles) to prevent divulging any proprietary information.

[image: Side-by-side demonstration of picture coming in badly on the left next to what it should look like on the right.]

I hope this makes it clear that I am having problems with the bounding boxes.  Perhaps they were loosely specified before, and at some point, what "bounding-box" would accept was tightened up and "corrected"?  Irrespective, the true problem isn't the bounding box issues, the true problem is how to successfully work with older versions without costing the company too much in terms of "bringing things up to date."

Here is the first bounding box problem:

```
\begin{figure}[!hbt]       
\begin{center}       
\includegraphics[bb = 0.00in 0.0in 6.0in 7.5in,       
width=0.95\textwidth,keepaspectratio,clip, trim = 0 0 0       
230,scale=1.5]{PAWS_RunScreen.jpg}       
\caption{Run Screen}       
\label{fig:runscreen}       
\end{center}       
\end{figure}
```

with its Log messages:

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 481.

<PAWS_RunScreen.jpg, id=62, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_RunScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_RunScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_RunScreen.jpg used on input line 481.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.
 [10 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_RunScreen.jpg>]
```

and the second bounding box error:

```
\vspace{0.70in}      
\begin{figure}[!hbt]       
\begin{center}        
\includegraphics[bb = 0.00in 0.0in 6.0in 7.5in,       
width=0.95\textwidth,keepaspectratio,clip, trim = 0 0 0       
230,scale=2.3]{PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg}       
\vspace{-1.2in}
\caption{Run Setup Screen}       
\label{runsetup}       
\end{center}       
\end{figure}
```

with its Log messages:

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 515.

<PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg, id=68, 578.16pt x 462.22687pt>
File: PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg used on input line 515.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1329.7665pt x 532.13614pt.
```

and the third bounding box error:

```
\vspace{0.05in}   
\begin{figure}  
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[bb = 0.00in 0.0in 6.0in 7.5in,       
width=0.95\textwidth,keepaspectratio,clip, trim = 0 0 0       
230,scale=1.5]{PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg}         
  \caption{Method Editor Screen}  
  \label{fig:me}  
\end{center}
\end{figure} 
\vspace{-0.3in}
```

with its associated Log messages:

```
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 581.

<PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg, id=78, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg used on input line 581.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.
```

---

The log file had a lot of this pattern, which I had to remove to make it fit:

```
Overfull \hbox (4.27394pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 561--562
 [][] 
  []
```

Here is the mostly complete Log file that results from PDF generation from TeXworks, modified to make it fit:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.6.4)  27 APR 2020 13:48
entering extended mode
**C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/pawsua_ug2_5.tex
(C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/pawsua_ug2_5.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, ..., welsh, loaded.
(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\specification.cls
Document Class: specification 2001/12/20 v1.4 Custom LaTeX document class
\@sbcurrent=\count79
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\tempa=\dimen102
\c@part=\count80
\c@Section=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@sectionpage=\count83
\c@subsection=\count84
\c@subsubsection=\count85
\c@paragraph=\count86
\c@subparagraph=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\c@figure=\count89
\headrulewidth=\dimen103
\footrulewidth=\dimen104
\headwidth=\dimen105
\EpsFig=\box26
)
(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\testplan.sty)
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(C:\MikTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\MikTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count90
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen106
\Gin@req@width=\dimen107
)
(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\rotating.sty
Package: rotating 1997/09/26, v2.13 Rotation package

(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
\c@r@tfl@t=\count91
\rot@float@box=\box27
)
(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\multirow\multirow.sty
\bigstrutjot=\dimen108
)
(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\comment.sty
\CommentStream=\write3

Excluding comment 'comment') (C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
Package: tabularx 1999/01/07 v2.07 `tabularx' package (DPC)

(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\tools\array.sty
Package: array 2008/09/09 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen109
\extrarowheight=\dimen110
\NC@list=\toks15
\extratabsurround=\skip41
\backup@length=\skip42
)
\TX@col@width=\dimen111
\TX@old@table=\dimen112
\TX@old@col=\dimen113
\TX@target=\dimen114
\TX@delta=\dimen115
\TX@cols=\count92
\TX@ftn=\toks16
) (C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\graphics\lscape.sty
Package: lscape 2000/10/22 v3.01 Landscape Pages (DPC)
) (C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\pawsua_ug2_5.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 72.

(C:\MikTeX\tex\latex\base\omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 1999/05/25 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <9> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <9> on input line 72.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 72.
 [1

{C:/Users/dev/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on line 74.
 [2

]
(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\pawsua_ug2_5.toc
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 2.
 [1

] [2])
\tf@toc=\write4

(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\pawsua_ug2_5.lot)
\tf@lot=\write5

(C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\pawsua_ug2_5.lof [3])
\tf@lof=\write6
 [4]
[1

] 
2: Station Overview
[4]
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on line 270.
 [5] [6]
[9]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 481.

<PAWS_RunScreen.jpg, id=62, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_RunScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_RunScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_RunScreen.jpg used on input line 481.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.
 [10 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_RunScreen.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 515.

<PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg, id=68, 578.16pt x 462.22687pt>
File: PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_RunSetupScreen.jpg used on input line 515.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1329.7665pt x 532.13614pt.

[12]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 581.

<PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg, id=78, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg used on input line 581.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.

[13

 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_MethodScreen.jpg>]

[14] [15]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 697.

<PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityLength.jpg, id=91, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityLength.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityLength.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityLength.jpg used on input li
ne 697.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.

[16

 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityLength.jpg
>]
Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 836.

<PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityMotion.jpg, id=103, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityMotion.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityMotion.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityMotion.jpg used on input li
ne 836.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 881.

<PAWS_ProductScreen_Force.jpg, id=105, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_ProductScreen_Force.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_ProductScreen_Force.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_ProductScreen_Force.jpg used on input line 881.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.
 [19] [20 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_ProductScreen_VelocityM
otion.jpg>] [21 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_ProductScreen_For
ce.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 907.

<PAWS_DataScreen.jpg, id=119, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_DataScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_DataScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_DataScreen.jpg used on input line 907.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: -1174.89139pt x -1442.13919pt.
 [22

 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_DataScreen.jpg>]
[25]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 1040.

<PAWS_CalibrationScreen.jpg, id=135, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_CalibrationScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_CalibrationScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_CalibrationScreen.jpg used on input line 1040.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.

[26

 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_CalibrationScreen.jpg>]
[27]
Missing character: There is no ’ in font cmti10!
 [28]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 1149.

<PAWS_UtilitiesScreen.jpg, id=148, 832.61063pt x 565.36218pt>
File: PAWS_UtilitiesScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_UtilitiesScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_UtilitiesScreen.jpg used on input line 1149.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 1248.91289pt x 501.74745pt.
 [29

 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_UtilitiesScreen.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 1167.

<PAWS_DiagnosticsScreen.jpg, id=154, 578.16pt x 462.22687pt>
File: PAWS_DiagnosticsScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_DiagnosticsScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_DiagnosticsScreen.jpg used on input line 1167.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 867.23787pt x 347.04485pt.
 [30

 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_DiagnosticsScreen.jpg>]
[31

]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1229.

<MT_SAG285_BalanceScreen.jpg, id=164, 786.94pt x 468.75125pt>
File: MT_SAG285_BalanceScreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use MT_SAG285_BalanceScreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: MT_SAG285_BalanceScreen.jpg used on line 1229.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 1180.40712pt x 356.83138pt.
 [32 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/MT_SAG285_BalanceScreen.jpg>]
[33

]
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 1253.

LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 37.16692pt on line 1296.

[34]
Missing character: There is no – in font cmr10!
 [35

]
Overfull \hbox (8.62225pt too wide) in parag @ lines 1366--1373
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 Run re-ports can be re-viewed/approved by 
se-lect-ing the \O T1/cmr/bx/n/10.95 Mark as Re-viewed/Approved
 []

[36

] [37]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) - using `viewport' instead on line 1411.

<PAWS_reviewscreen.jpg, id=186, 452.4403pt x 328.22626pt>
File: PAWS_reviewscreen.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_reviewscreen.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_reviewscreen.jpg used on input line 1411.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 678.65881pt x 146.04442pt.
 [38 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_reviewscreen.jpg>]

[39] [40

] [41] [42] [43]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1583.

<PAWS_methodrpt2.jpg, id=208, 1946.02031pt x 1219.55624pt>
File: PAWS_methodrpt2.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_methodrpt2.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_methodrpt2.jpg used on input line 1583.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 486.50389pt x 247.17268pt.
[44 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_methodrpt2.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1602.

<PAWS_productrpt.jpg, id=214, 434.37282pt x 556.32843pt>
File: PAWS_productrpt.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_productrpt.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_productrpt.jpg used on input line 1602.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 651.55762pt x 488.19685pt.
[45]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1622.

<PAWS_calhistoryrpt.jpg, id=219, 437.38406pt x 336.50719pt>
File: PAWS_calhistoryrpt.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_calhistoryrpt.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_calhistoryrpt.jpg used on line 1622.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 656.07446pt x 158.46579pt.
 [46 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_productrpt.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1638.

<PAWS_curcalrpt.jpg, id=225, 435.12563pt x 519.44063pt>
File: PAWS_curcalrpt.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use PAWS_curcalrpt.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_curcalrpt.jpg used on input line 1638.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 652.68683pt x 432.86528pt.
 [47 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_calhistoryrpt.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1657.

<PAWS_runrptp1.jpg, id=231, 438.13687pt x 551.81157pt>
File: PAWS_runrptp1.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
 <use PAWS_runrptp1.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_runrptp1.jpg used on input line 1657.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 657.20367pt x 481.42159pt.

[48 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_curcalrpt.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1671.

<PAWS_runrptp2.jpg, id=237, 391.4625pt x 552.56438pt>
File: PAWS_runrptp2.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
 <use PAWS_runrptp2.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_runrptp2.jpg used on input line 1671.
(pdftex.def) Requested size: 587.19229pt x 482.55077pt.

[49 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_runrptp1.jpg>]

Package pdftex.def Warning: Option `bb' does not make sense,
(pdftex.def) using `viewport' instead on line 1684.

<PAWS_runrptp3.jpg, id=244, 403.5075pt x 551.05875pt>
File: PAWS_runrptp3.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
 <use PAWS_runrptp3.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: PAWS_runrptp3.jpg used on input line 1684.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 605.25977pt x 480.29234pt.

[50 <C:/VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_runrptp2.jpg>] [51 <C:/VIDEOS
_DESKTOP_CAPTURES/PAWSUA_UG2_5/PAWS_runrptp3.jpg>] 
F: Service
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in parag @ lines 1711--1720
 []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in parag @ lines 1711--1720
 []

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in parag @ lines 1711--1720
 []
[52

] [53] (C:\VIDEOS_DESKTOP_CAPTURES\PAWSUA_UG2_5\pawsua_ug2_5.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1399 strings out of 493921
 18919 string characters out of 3154507
 80525 words of memory out of 3000000
 4673 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 11650 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 29i,15n,29p,442b,310s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/MikTeX/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmcsc10.pfb><C:/MikTeX
/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmmi6.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi9.pfb><C:/MikTeX/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fo
nts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr6.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr9.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl12.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts
/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmsy9.pfb><C:/MikTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on pawsua_ug2_5.pdf (59 pages, 2500488 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 309 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 210 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: I don't remember when miktex 2.1 was current, but it must be at least 15 years.  Are your files so old? Which class and packages are they using?

Comment: even latex sources that are 15 years old are rather unlikely to have different line breaking if used with current latex (it is possible, but unlikely)  as you have shown no code nor shown the warnings you are getting it is rather hard to help

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Not necessarily our files are 15 years old, but that LaTeX dev environment is what we've been using for a long time, yes, probably 15 years.  The company is 30 years old.  document-class: specification.cls.  packages: testplan, graphicx, rotating, multirow, comment, tabularx, & lscape.

Comment: It is not possible to give you any advice without more details about your code and the errors you get in a current system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Added more details about the code and the errors we are getting, as you asked.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Have added some of the code, and also warnings, according to your request.

Comment: The bounding message is a warning, not an error. You are overdoing in your settings. Why are you setting a width *and* a scale factor? Can't you simply correct the options?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Please see picture I added to show problem I am having with bounding box issues.

Comment: Well obviously the clip + trim option now do what they are supposed to do: they clip the image. Try only `\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{....}`

Comment: BTw: your log-file shows that you are actually using the files and format from 2011.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - As I pointed out before, this is a 30-year old company doing this, and yes, I expect them to have some stuff that "just works" lying around, still working.  To me, it is a textament to how stable LaTeX itself is, and to me points to underlying foundations of either math or logic (math's cousin) which also don't change.  Yet I still need to decide whether to slowly migrate documents as they are updated, or leave them in MiKTeX 2.1, which actually doesn't seem to be that different from MiKTeX 2.9, because the user guide mostly renders just fine.

Comment: You shouldn't use clip if you don't want to clip. I also bet that you are using the wrong driver for graphics. So if it worked it was more or less by chance and while we care about stability we do not promise that wrong syntax or input will continue to work in all eternity. Btw: you are not using miktex 2.1. Your binaries are from miktex 2.9. You are only using an older latex and older packages.