# How to install and run two side-by-side versions of LaTeX / TeXmF? -- MiKTeX 2.1 and MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: installing, windows, texmf, sidebyside

I am a new user to both LaTeX and this Stack Exchange, so please go easy on me!

I posted this question, ["Can the older MiKTeX 2.1 files be used with the newer MiKTeX 2.9 and its TeXworks user interface"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/540469/can-the-older-miktex-2-1-files-be-used-with-the-newer-miktex-2-9-and-its-texwork?noredirect=1), and I thought about accomplishing what my company wants to do another way.

We have thousands of *.tex files created with the legacy MiKTeX 2.1, which I understand is about 15 years old.  Our documents are rather simple, and a lot of them use just about the same "formatting".  The >100 page user manual I am working on uses document-class "specification.cls", and for packages, it uses testplan, graphicx, rotating, multirow, comment, tabularx, & lscape.

I was not oriented when brought on board this company, and have already created several LaTeX documents under the current MiKTeX 2.9, but my instructions to be able to work with the MiKTeX 2.1 are to uninstall the MiKTeX 2.9 to work with 2.1 using only the TeXmF directory.  I set the path to only the 2.1 directory, but everything (TeXworks and the 2.1 directory executables) are still picking up the 2.9 behavior.

Can I somehow (like Java does) work with two different MiKTeX installations, using the TeXmF directories, and have them stay in their own little areas and respect Windows path settings, instead whatever hidden thing they are listening to (probably windows registry).

That's my question.  Can I have side-by-side installations of MiKTeX 2.1 and MiKTeX 2.9, and have them operate properly, as I need to update *.tex files, slowly transitioning those LaTeX documents over (for those that render differently, like the relatively big user guide I am currently working on).  It's not really the one document problem -- it's the thousands-of-documents problem.  Thanks.

---

EDIT:  When I said that I have created several LaTeX documents already, I really just copied existing LaTeX documents from my company network and modified the verbiage (textual content).  I am really very much a newbie here, though I am a developer.

Comment: It wouldn't be easy (if possible at all) to use the 2.1. binaries. You could use packages from the old system. But I don't think it is worth the time. From the code in your other question I gather that you only need to correct the includegraphics options. So better spent your time on this. It should be done in short time with a bit search & replace.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - I just used the 2.1 binaries to successfully generate a PDF with the graphics coming in properly -- but I had to uninstall MiKTeX 2.9 first.  I appreciate your opinion that it is not worth the time, but I'm not sure that I agree yet... You see, there are all of those thousands of other files that I don't know what I will encounter.

Comment: yes that is what I meant: you can't use both.

Comment: I unzipped the 2.1 TeXmF directory, added the path to the binary directory (TeXmF\bin) and in the development document directory called "latex UserGuide.tex" twice, and "dvipdfm UserGuide" to get the pdf.  (as I was directed).

Comment: Just curious why I couldn't have two different TeXmF directories (one MiKTeX 2.1, and the other MiKTeX 2.9) and just change the windows path to point to the one I wanted to use.  Are there "USB" versions?

Comment: With texlive that would be possible (I have a number of texlive system running) but miktex uses the windows registry and that makes it complicated. But even if it were possible: I wouldn't do it. You have no real idea which difference is causing the problem and are now doing cargo magic hoping to hit something. For example in your other question you were using pdflatex and now you suddenly run latex + dvipdfm. Did you check your document in miktex 2.9 with latex+dvipdfm?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Good catch with seeing that I was using two different paths to generate the pdfs.  But, with miktex 2.9, I did get a dvi with latex, and then viewed the dvi directly and saw that the graphics were still being messed-up in the same way.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Are any of your TexLive systems different versions?

Comment: I have texlive versions from 2012 to 2020. I could get older one if needed from the historic repository.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Cool!  Thank you!  This is one of the pieces I really needed to know, and should be most helpful.  Thank you again!

Comment: i'm not sure if this is helpful. They contain also older binaries. Imho using new binaries is better - less bugs. You probably need only a few older packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- I also used to think, similarly to how you think above, that all Cobol should be brought current, until I looked at [Wikipedia -- Cobol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL#COBOL_2002_and_object-oriented_COBOL), and found that, "In 1997, Gartner Group estimated that there were a total of 200 billion lines of COBOL in existence, which ran 80% of all business programs." So when you say "Imho using new binaries is better - less bugs" you are ignoring the extent of our current LaTeX investment & the man-years it will take to, as you repeatedly chant, "Upgrade! Upgrade! Upgrade!"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- I said "We have thousands of *.tex files".  Your responses show that you did not trust my assessment, or accept my parameters for a solution.